# How to get software version before update (Windows)

Tags: windows, event-log

I'm troubleshooting my Dino-Lenovo running Windows to play optical media. After updating VLC, I get more errors with the update. I would like to downgrade to the previously installed version. I think I skipped a few versions in between.

How can I get the previous version number before the update?

Event Viewer?

// NOTE: I removed unrelated keywords which might be leading peeps to find my question and determine it unhelpful to the larger topic.

Comment: You mention you are receiving an error?  It would be nice if you included, what error you received, I assume you are talking about the desktop version of VLC?  Which version of VLC do you actually have installed?

Comment: It would help if you indicated which version you previously installed.  I went ahead an submitted an answer, but in order to have a (valid) reference point, you really should indicate which version you have installed and which version you are looking for.

Comment: There. I updated the OP. The post isn't _about_ VLC. That's just for context. In ArchLinux, you can find the previous version of an app using this little bit from the console: `grep "\(upgraded\|installed\) $pkg" /var/log/pacman.log`. This is because `/var/log/pacman.log` is the log for the package handler on Arch.

Comment: Windows does not keep track of this information, if it isn't in an event, then it does not exist.  If there isn't a installation log that indicates which version was removed, before the current version was installed, then the information does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the Windows Event Viewer, you can search in the

"Windows Logs> Application"

logs for "video", if VLC ever had an error it will be logged and show the version number. Pick an error date before you upgraded.

Only other thing you can do is look for any install logs vlc may have created, usually found in the users profile Temp folder.

[image]

Comment: Great idea, but no luck. Searching `Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application`. Then from the right sidebar I select `Find --> Find what: video`. I get a popup: _"Searching from the selected event to the end of the list, there is no event that contains the specified string."_ It's the same for Apps and System. There are 60k system events and 30k App events. I tried "VLC", too.

Comment: This is an error event, so there will be less, you can filter the logs and only show event 1000 instances, then look that those for any VLC caused errors.

Comment: Only other thing I can suggest is to see if VLC left behind any logs when you upgraded, usually found in the user profile Temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the previous version number before the update?

I am going to assume the version you have installed is 3.0.2, and the previous version you are talking about, is 3.0.1 which means you can download that [here](https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.1/)  Otherwise since you indicated you skipped several versions, you can download 3.0.0 [here](https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.0/) and any other version can be downloaded [here](https://get.videolan.org/vlc/) in the associated folder.

Answer (score -4):

### OldVersion.com

Without knowing the previous version, you can always get older verions of VLC here, uninstall the current VLC and install older versions until your error resolves.:

http://www.oldversion.com/windows/vlc-media-player/